# What can be the reason multi-meter shows continuity even though there is isolation?

Tags: isolation

I'm dealing with a module where the block diagram is given as follows:

[image]

The datasheet can be found both at [here](https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/scm5b30_31.pdf) and an alternative one [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/5B30_31.pdf).

When I perform a continuity test with a multi-meter between I/O Common and the Power Common pins, there is continuity and the multi-meter shows 0 Ohm.

But it seems according to what the datasheet tells and so the block diagram there must be isolation between these pins. Can I be wrong making conclusions about isolation by using a multi-meter?

Comment: Is this module wired up?

Comment: Yes actually there is a ready back panel called SCMPB03-2 it is mounted on. The back panel details ar here https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/SCMPB03and4.pdf

Comment: So, if you unplug the module and check between the pins, what do you read?

Comment: The datasheet has this interesting note: *"The output common must be kept within +/-3 V of power common"* which implies there may be a current path internal to the device between those points.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If I do that I dont observe continuity for two pins I checked.

Comment: Then the back panel is providing the continuity, not the module.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are jumpers, that are not shown as installed, but are installed by default on your back panel:

[image]

Given the comment Peter Smith noted about keeping voltage between I/O common and power common low (< 3V), we might assume there is something like a TVS in there, and the intended purpose of the isolation is just to prevent ground loops, so it's intended to be connected at some defined external point.

Comment: But how come it makes it isolated as they claim?

Comment: Don't understand the question.

Comment: @atmnt: The isolation claim appears solely related to input and output isolation.

Comment: What confuses me is this. If at the end of the day they provide path between those two pins what is the point to isolate the power ground and I/O ground inside the module since they violate that isolation  anyway later when mounted. Hope more clear what I dont get. Thanks

Comment: @atmnt Think of the power common as being for power and conducting a fair amount of current. So any trace or wire you connect to that will have some voltage drop. Your I/O ground is the reference ground for your output signal. You would like that to be connected to a point, such as the input of a data acquisition system. No current to speak of flows through that conductor. So if you have several modules connected to one power supply **and** the input of your data acquisition system is common between channels you would want **only one** jumper. Otherwise one on each channel.